# How to prove that an equivalence relation $E$ over a set $A$ satisfying $|A|^3=|A|$ will satisfy $|E|=|A|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals, equivalence-relations

> Given set $A$, $|A| = a$ and $a^{3} = a$. Let $E$ be an equivalence relation over $A.$
>
> Prove that $|E| = a$

**My Attempt -**

We know that there isn't any finite set $A$ such that $|A|^{3} = |A|$, therefore $A$ is an infinite set.

By definition equivalence relation $E$ over and infinite set $A$ -

$E$ is an equivalence relation $ \iff I_A \subseteq E$ (let $I_A$ be the identity relation over set $A$), and all equivalence relation $E$ over $A$ uphold $E \subseteq A \times A$ (that part am i not sure of).

Therefore, $I_A \subseteq E \subseteq A \times A$, translating to cardinals of infinite sets - $a = |I_A| \le |E| \le |A \times A| = a$.

$\Rightarrow |E| = a$

Am  i correct ? are my mathematical assumptions right ? Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: And assuming $|A| \ge \aleph_0$ ?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that.  The argument you give works for any infinite set.

Comment: @Ross: If an infinite cardinal satisfies $a^3=a$, then it has to be $a\geq\aleph_0$...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: are you thinking in the absence of choice?  I thought all infinite cardinals were $\ge \aleph_0$

Comment: @Ross: I do, do, do. Because your reply was "You shouldn't assume that", which makes it seem like you're saying "even without assuming that for an infinite $A$, $|A|\geq\aleph_0$". But I see now that you might have meant that the argument works for the finite cases as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ has $0$ or $1$ element we have $|A|^3=|A|$, so $A$ can be finite.  Your argument works for the finite case as well.

Comment: Why do you need to handle the case of $0$ and $1$ separately? It's the same proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I was thinking of the part where he says $A$ has to be finite, but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is essentially correct. Essentially because it doesn't use the assumption that $A$ is infinite, which as pointed out is incorrect since $0^3=0$ and $1^3=1$ as well.

But the proof works just fine for these two finite cases as well.